# How to open pdf or txt files by filedialog.askopenfile in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter

## How could I open the pdf or txt file after I use filedialog.askopenfile in tkinter?

## Is there any posibility that after I select the file on that folder and press open, to be opened # by its specific program ('Adobe reader')?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


def open_file():
    return fd.askopenfile()


window = Tk()
b_open = Button(window, text='Open file', command=open_file)
b_open.grid(row=0, column=0)

window.geometry('250x80')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: First use `askopenfilename()` instead of `askopenfile()` if you want to get the filename only.  Second if your platform is Windows, you can use `os.startfile()` to open the file with the default program, for example `os.startfile('sample.pdf')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for opening files with their default programs:

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog  # import needed modules

tk = Tk()
tk.geometry('700x600')  # initialize tkinter window


def x():
    f = filedialog.askopenfilename()  # create function for opening file
    webbrowser.open(f)


btn = Button(text="open file", command=x)  # make a button to call x
btn.pack()

mainloop()  # update
```

when you run this code, the following should happen:

The tkinter window opens, giving you a open file button

[image]

When you click the button, you will be prompted to select a file

[image]

After you select the file it will open in its default program. this will work for any kind of file.

[image]

Say you wanted to open a file with a specific program, you would use the built in `subprocess` module like so:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog  # import needed modules
import subprocess
tk = Tk()
tk.geometry('700x600')  # initialize tkinter window


def x():  # make open file function
    f = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Program Files\\GIMP 2\\bin\\gimp-2.10.exe", f])  # path of program and opened file
    returncode = p.wait()  # wait for notepad to exit


btn = Button(text="open file", command=x)  # make a button to execute the 
function
btn.pack()

mainloop()  # update
```

Always make sure to specify the full file path of the program you are using to open the file. Also, if there are any slashes in the path of the program you are using to open the file (these \ ), make sure to add one more slash after each of them like I did.
both of these methods will work with any file type. Happy coding!